# PHP's $_SESSION with jQuery load() is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I am trying to insert a login form with jQuery's `load` method into a larger webpage (Grails gsp). Users are managed by a PHP backend, which should provide different versions of the login form, depending on the user being logged in or not.

When I call the PHP address directly (browser), the correct form is loaded - but with jQuery's `load` the `$_SESSION` is always empty and only the form for logged-out users is displayed.

What part of PHP's `$_SESSION` am I missing? Or is it a jQuery problem?

Edit, PHP Code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$template_dir = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'/'));

$root_dir = substr($template_dir,0,strrpos($template_dir,'/'));

$show_loginform = isset($_GET['show_loginform']) ? true : false;
$username = isset($_SESSION['login']['username']) ? $_SESSION['login']['username'] : 'Anonymous'; // always 'Anonymous' when using jQuery load
?>
...
```

Greetings,
smon

Comment: how can you fetch session data with jquery?

Comment: In your backend do you regenerate the session ID? I've previously had problems with managing user logins and using AJAX that was due to the session ID regenerating but not keeping it consistent among the loaded page and pages loaded via AJAX

Comment: It would help if there was some actual code to look at.

Comment: @Jonathon It really seems like the jQuery load creates a new session ID each time. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes. I set everything up so that on a normal page load it would regenerate the session ID, but on a page that was loaded via AJAX it wouldn't. I did this by simply setting a flag `$ajax` so if `$ajax` is `false` it will regenerate the session ID otherwise, nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem by adding my Grails app to my tomcat's `workers.properties` file. PHP Backend and Grails were running on the same server, but the differing port (8080 vs. 80) caused PHP to recreate the session each time the page was loaded.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.